# How to inject multiple EJB in a JUnit test class

Tags: java, junit, ejb

I'm trying to test a class that has multiples EJB that are connected with other EJB.

How do i inject all EJB from that class into a JUnit test class?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should not inject all dependencies. You should use frameworks like Mockito for simulation/mocking those dependencies in order to test your EJB.
Suppose you have the following bean:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceBean implements Service {

    @Inject
    private Dao dao;  

    public boolean insert(Someclass someClass){
        return dao.insert(someClass);
    }

}
```

You should use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to mock `Dao` (which should be an interface, not a concrete class) in this way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceBeanTest { 

    @Mock
    private Dao daoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceBean bean;

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
        when(daoMock.insert(Matchers.any(SomeClass.class))).thenReturn(true);
        assertTrue(bean.insert(new Someclass()));
    }

}
```

What's happening here:

- Mockito is creating a mock object from the interface `Dao`, which will mimic an implementation;
- This mock will be injected into `ServiceBean` instance;
- Using method `when` you instruct your mock.
- Your unit test verifies only `ServiceBean` behavior, does not perform any tests on dependencies, which should be tested in another test class. This allows you to isolate components in your class.

Mockito site contains various tutorials on how to perform this correctly.

Comment: Sure! https://github.com/LoreScianatico/J2EESample/blob/master/library.backend-ejb/src/test/java/com/lorescianatico/library/category/service/impl/CategoryServiceBeanTest.java here there is an example, just start here, I promise that I will update my answer as soon as possible with a complete example.